# Joining results of two joins

Tags: sql, join

I am looking for the best way to create a query that will do the following(Note: This is just an example, I know this example can be written better, my real goal is a much more complex example, but follows a similar structure)

```
items
       item_id   |   name      | cost

       1         |   Water     | 1.00
       2         |   Chips     | 1.50

trans_local

       local_id           |   item_id   |  date

       1                  |   1         | '2018-03-12'
       2                  |   1         | '2018-03-13'
       3                  |   2         | '2018-03-13'         

trans_international

       international_id   |   item_id   |  currency | date

       1                  |   1         |  'GBP'    | '2018-03-11'
       2                  |   2         |  'EUR'    | '2018-03-12'
       3                  |   2         |  'GBP'    | '2018-03-12'
```

I'm looking to create a select statement a table that lists all transactions in it.

```
 local_id   | international_id |  item_id | item_name | item_cost | currency | date

 1          | null             |  1       | Water     | 1.00      | null     | '2018-03-12'
 2          | null             |  1       | Water     | 1.00      | null     | '2018-03-13'
 3          | null             |  2       | Chips     | 1.50      | null     | '2018-03-13'
 null       | 1                |  1       | Water     | 1.00      | 'GBP'    | '2018-03-11'
 null       | 2                |  2       | Chips     | 1.50      | 'EUR'    | '2018-03-12'
 null       | 3                |  2       | Chips     | 1.50      | 'GBP'    | '2018-03-12'
```

`items` should be joined to either `trans_local` or `trans_international`.  I know I can do this with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`,  but I am unsure how to get results of all transactions together.  I believe it would be a `FULL JOIN` but getting everything together is confusing me a bit.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` items on both trans_local and trans_international and you got it.

Comment: So just something like `SELECT * FROM items LEFT JOIN trans_local ON items.item_id = trans_local.item_id LEFT JOIN trans_international ON items.item_id = trans_international.item_id`?

Comment: Yeah, and instead your `SELECT *` choose the columns you want to display

Comment: This is not giving me null results on the line.  I think a union will likely have to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the the only way to achieve your result is to use a UNION query, something like following:

```
(
  SELECT
    NULL as international_id,
    trans_local.local_id,
    items.name as item_name,
    items.cost as item_cost,
    NULL as currency,
    trans_local.date as date
  FROM items
  LEFT JOIN trans_local ON items.item_id = trans_local.item_id
)    
UNION
(
  SELECT
    trans_international.international_id as international_id,
    NULL as local_id,
    items.name as item_name,
    items.cost as item_cost,
    trans_international.currency as currency,
    trans_international.date as date
  FROM items
  LEFT JOIN trans_international ON items.item_id = trans_international.item_id
)
```

Comment: Welcome :-) Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

```
select local_id , international_id, A.item_id, item_name, item_cost,
currency, B.DATE
from items A
left outer join
trans_local B
on (A.item_id = B.item_id)
left outer join
trans_international C
on (A.item_id = C.item_id)
```

as per your requirement your item_id column is having all the values. so find the column on table for which u want all the values and make it as left outer join.

Comment: It seems like when I do this,I am getting full results for the whole row rather than some results nulled, I think like a couple of the others said, a union will likely have to be used

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `union all`:

```
select i.*, t.*
from ((select local_id, NULL as internationalid, item_id, null as currency, date
       from trans_local
      ) union all
      (select NULL as local_id, internationalid, item_id, currency, date
       from trans_international
      )
     ) t join
     item i
     on t.item_id = i.item_id;
```